# how to fix not generated css file from less while run static deploy command in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1

Magento Version 2.1.9
Current Mode: production

After switched from developer to production mode, I ran the static deploy command but in that, I got the following error on CLI

```
$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
Requested languages: en_US
Requested areas: frontend, adminhtml
Requested themes: Magento/blank, Magento/luma, Sm/market, Magento/backend
=== frontend -> Magento/blank -> en_US ===
=== frontend -> Magento/luma -> en_US ===
=== frontend -> Sm/market -> en_US ===
=== adminhtml -> Magento/backend -> en_US ===
```

---

```
Compilation from source: /home/<yoursite.com>/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email.less
Compilation from source: 
frontend/Sm/market/en_US/css/email.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/market/en_US/Magento_Bundle/css/source/_email.less'
```

---

```
Compilation from source: /home/<yoursite.com>/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-inline.less
Compilation from source: 
frontend/Sm/market/en_US/css/email-inline.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/market/en_US/Magento_Bundle/css/source/_email.less'
```

and due to this, above mention files are not generated on the pub/static folder so please suggest to me how to fix it in production mode?

Comment: you tried this command with sudo ?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info to detect the problem.
Please answer some questions to debug your problems.

- Show more theme structure
- theme.js
- did you have any email.less file on your theme??
- Did you have any ***file.less*** include ***_email.less*** in *Magento_Bundle* module?
- If you have file **source.less** or **_module.less** have included **_email.less** please remove that line, because default magento auto load *emaill.less* >> [Style Email Template In Magento 2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html)
- Please check any empty *.less* files then remove them.